# How do I setup an LXC guest so that it gets a dhcp address so I can access it on my network?

Tags: networking, lxc

I setup LXC using:

```
lxc-create -t ubuntu -n lxcguest1
```

But I can't access any services running on it from my LAN, it appears to be NATed.  How do I set it up so that I can access it (it probably needs to get it's dhcp address from my Linksys router)?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/256304/public-ip-address-for-lxc-container/311003#311003

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just dealt with this issue myself. Basically you need to setup a bridge and bind your network card and container to it. Here is the article I followed:

http://bj0z.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/howto-build-a-base-lxc-container-in-ubuntu-11-04/

Sounds as if like me, you require the 'bridge' solution rather than the NAT solution.
I also turned off the default LXC bridge setup (which is NAT'ed). To do this just edit the file: `/etc/default/lxc` and change `USE_LXC_BRIDGE="TRUE"` to `USE_LXC_BRIDGE="FALSE"` and reboot.

Comment: I am a little confused by this solution: it says he needs to setup a bridge, then says the solution is to turn off the default bridge setup.  Surely he must switch ON a bridge setup.  The second thing I need help with is that User says that the bridge setup is NATed, Surely it's either bridged (so the containers is on the same network as the host) or is NATed (on a different network and requires routing).  My understanding is that these are mutually exclusive?

Comment: This is all invalid now with the current versions.  /etc/default/lx* is completely gone.

Answer (score 5):

My setup on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (Trusty Tahr) hosts

Add to `/etc/network/interfaces` on the host

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 0.0.0.0

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0
```

(reboot after changes)

And on the container config files (`/var/lib/lxc/containername/config`) I set `lxc.network.link = br0`

With this the container will get public ip addresses from the dhcp server just like the host.

Comment: @JonathanY. The br0 should appear after adding it to /etc/network/interfaces as stated in the answer. You might need a reboot.

Comment: Thanks. What I was missing was needing to add `<username> veth br0 2`  to `/etc/lxc/lxc-usernet` in order to use `br0` with unprivileged containers.

Answer (score 2):

I used the default Ubuntu LXC settings, and configured my router to send all traffic on 10.0.3.xxx to the Ubuntu machine. On a DD-WRT enabled router, the settings look something like the screenshot below. Replace `192.168.1.137` with the IP of the machine running LXC. Other routers should have similar options to set up a static route (here are [static route instructions for Linksys](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/set-up-static-routing-linksys-52531.html), for example).

[image: DD-WRT settings for static routing to LXC]

This is unrelated, but I also used the DNSMasq service to point a hostname to the LXC container's IP address. This way I can access the container at `http://gitlab/` anywhere on the network. In my opinion it's a lot easier to use a hostname to access a container than remember the IP address.

[image: DD-WRT DNSMasq settings]

Comment: Nice approach - try. Thumbs up! Adding static route works - and router itself can ping containerized machines! But with many ISP supplied routers port forwarding won't work due to: `Error code: 4937

The IP address is not in the same subnet with LAN IP address. Please input another one.`  (router holds 192.168.x.x subnet, whilst LXD/LXC are on 10.0.x.x subnet)

Comment: Yes, your router will need to accept a subnet mask for my solution to work. I like to buy a router and add an [after-market firmware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_router_firmware_projects) to make crazy configurations possible :-p

Comment: I'm using MikroTik at both home and office, but this was for one setup where they had plain router supplied by ISP. So your idea is very simple yet very effective - KISS principle :) I like it and will use it for sure as I cannot get it how those containers they don't have yet a solution to expose them into external world.