# Juju GUI public IP

Tags: networking, vmware, juju

I have been trying to install juju with juju-gui on my virtual machine (Fresh installation Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit)

To configure my local environment I installed mongodb-server and lxc.

After successfully installing juju and juju-gui, I run `watch juju status` and get public ip: 10.0.3.213 for juju-gui.

Since I am running server version of ubuntu I have no way of seeing that URL from this virtual machine. Using my host OS I can't reach that IP since that IP is being used by lxc.

Is this a default way of accessing juju?

If I remove lxc would I be able to access GUI on eth0 ip address?

Comment: If I remove lxc juju can't work.

Answer (score 4):

You will probably find what you're looking for here: [How do I setup an LXC guest so that it gets a dhcp address so I can access it on my network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231666/how-do-i-setup-an-lxc-guest-so-that-it-gets-a-dhcp-address-so-i-can-access-it-on)

Alternatively if you are looking for a temporary solution you can create an ssh tunnel to the GUI machine by: `ssh -N -p 22 -c 3des hostUser@hostIp -L 1234/lxcMachineIp/443` and then you will be able to access it on your local machine at `https://localhost:1234`

Answer (score 1):

The IP range 10.0.3.* and therefore the juju-gui assigned IP  10.0.3.213 come from the lxc default configuration. Follow these steps :

1. Clean-up

   - uninstall `juju`, `juju-gui` etc.
   - delete "local-machine" lxc files, if any 
     `rm -rf  /var/lib/lxc/*`
2. configure LXC

   - edit  `/etc/init/lxc-net.conf` and `/etc/default/lxc-net` and set your LAN IP range, 
     e.g. instead  of `10.0.3.*` your LAN is `10.1.2.*`, then set 
     `LXC_ADDR="10.1.2.4"` 
      
     `LXC_NETWORK="10.1.2.0/24"` 
      
     `LXC_DHCP_RANGE="10.1.2.201,10.1.2.250"` 
      
     `LXC_DHCP_MAX="50"`
      
     Actually the LXC_ADDR should be the I.P. of your `"lxcbr0"` bridge.
   - Optionally you may edit `/etc/lxc/dnsmasq.conf` and give STATIC IPs to LXC containers (within the `LXC_DHCP_RANGE` I.P. range).
3. reboot the machine and reinstall `juju`, `juju-gui` etc.

By the way LXC is only necessary if you deploy with juju on the `"local"` environment.